Unordered radiobutton options in Form-Builder
I'm working on a long form with "radio-button" type options and conditional rules to display the options. All good with this.
The problem is that when I have created a new container with the custom radio type fields, these are displayed side by side and not in a single column.

I already checked "show one option per line" when creating the custom fields.

I've also tried changing the way the elements inside the container are displayed in the form-builder options and this doesn't work for me.

I've tried to add custom CSS but that only negatively affects the radio options.
 input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
  }

How can I display the radio options in a single column (one below the other)?
This is the form: https://crm.ingenium.org.mx/civicrm/solicitud-admision/

What version are you on? I think show option per line = 1 should work as expected. Can you replicate the same on demo site - https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/?

@jitendra-fuzion I'm using version 5.72.1 in WordPress. I also thought that putting 1 option per line in the custom field settings would fix it but it didn't.

Can you replicate the same on wordpress demo site? https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM.
